# Why is this MySQL query taking unproportionally much longer when adding 1 or 2 characters to the search string?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, innodb, database-performance

I have got following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%15%'
                      AND text LIKE '%10%'
                      AND text LIKE '%202%';
```

There are about 40 000 entries in table with text content of about 60 000 characters.

When i execute the query its fairly fast... duration is about 0,05 seconds.

The thing is when i add just two characters to the last string it takes already 15 full seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%15%'
                      AND text LIKE '%10%'
                      AND text LIKE '%2020i%';
```

Notice the difference between `202` and `2020i`.

The funny thing is this somehow relates to combining numbers and letters.

For example this query also executes in about 0,05 seconds alhtough there are more characters in the last string:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%15%'
                      AND text LIKE '%10%'
                      AND text LIKE '%information%';
```

Using `information2` instead of `information` though... the execution time rises to 17 seconds.

Could it be that some if this is caused by predefined character sets ? And certain patterns like "2i" or "i2" are interpreted by the DB in a certain way ? Just a thought...
The character set on all columns is `utf8` and collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

Thanks for any help !

EDIT:

Here the table in question !

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=889823 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourtablename;`

Comment: you must check EXLAIN of your quiery, as it will not find 2020i in your  tables, and idex will not help and mysql tries to find it anyway with a full table scann, have you thought about regexp or full text indexes

Comment: If the intent is to find "15" in the _middle_ of a "word", then `FULLTEXT` is useless.

Comment: I have edited the Question ! I am aware of the full text search. Thanks for all your replies. @ysth If it cannot find '%202%', it naturally cannot find '%2020i%' either... still one string takes about 0,05 secs and the other 15 seconds.

Comment: Huh.  Is there any difference in `explain select restofyourquery` for the good and bad queries?

Answer (score 1):

Full-text indexes are created on text-based columns (CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns) to speed up queries and DML operations on data contained within those columns.

[FULLTEXT index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html)

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FullText` ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'etc');
```

Comment: Full-text indexes are a tool to make natural language searches. They probably won't be useful to find across what looks like codes or references.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. There is already a fulltext index on the table. (Note the MyIsam engine) I am using the LIKE keyword though, as i am also trying to find certain patterns inside substrings of words. The question relates more to why it takes so much longer to search for 1 - 2 characters more !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer to my question why queries were taking so long is related to the collation setting of the particular `text` column. The collation `utf8` seems to have a massive performance impact when comparing strings. The default collation of the database is `latin1`, i am not sure if the performance impact appears because the database internally converts any data inside a column that is not the default charset to the default (`latin1`) or because the representation itself is just sub optimal when performing string matches, *nevertheless i guess that some character patterns just take unproportionally much longer when using `utf8` collation*. I changed the collation of `text` column to `latin1` and the query worked pretty fast again. It might not be the an actual answer to my question but a solution the my problem of queries being too slow.